# Python Spliting extracted CSV Data

Tags: python, csv, split

I have some data (taken from a CSV file) in the format:

```
 MyValues = [[2 2 2 1 1]
             [2 2 2 2 1]
             [1 2 2 1 1]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 2 2 1 1]
             [1 2 2 1 1]]
```

I would like to split this data into 2/3 and 1/3 and be able to distinguish between them. For example

```
twoThirds = [[2 2 2 1 1]
             [2 2 2 2 1]
             [1 2 2 1 1]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 1 2 1 2]]

 oneThird = [[2 1 2 1 2]
             [2 2 2 1 1]
             [1 2 2 1 1]]
```

I have tried to use the following code to achieve this, but am unsure if i have gone about this the correct way?

```
   twoThirds = (MyValues * 2) / 3 #What does this code provide me?
```

Comment: I am not certain of what you are asking. It looks like you are trying to slice the array.  twoThirds, oneThird = MyValues[:len(MyValues)*2/3], MyValues[len(MyValues)*2/3:].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a list, use the slice notation. And read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
In [59]: l = range(9)

In [60]: l[:len(l)/3*2]
Out[60]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [61]: l[len(l)/3*2:]
Out[61]: [6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You can also checkout this question on slice notation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation